# Deployment has been done, but...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, capistrano, unicorn

I'm creating a Rails app. I deployed to a vps server by Capistrano, running the following deploy command:

```
$ bundle exec cap production deploy
```

The deploying looked like success. And i checked my url, but the page hadn't changed(I use nginx)

[image]

Why? What should i do? if anyone understand this situation, please help me. Syota

**The specs are:**

```
ubuntu 16.04
Bundler 1.14.6
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision58053) [x86_64-darwin16]
Rails 5.1.2
capistrano 3
cloud9 (local environment)
nginx 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
unicorn 4.9.0-2build2
```

Comment: Upload nginx config file and reload nginx.

Comment: thanks for advice. nginx config file exists and i reloaded, but not changing.